# How to read multiband ENVI image in R and write multiband ENVI image as the same size as input

Tags: r, image-processing, raster

Firstly, I want to read multilayer (10) ENVI image in R and then run some program on it. Finally I want to export the output into ENVI image at the size with input image. The size of input image is ncol= 200, nrow=350, Layer=10). The type of input image is floating point. How to write code in R to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add some data or provide access to them? You will 'run some program on it' outside R? you just want to get it in another format? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to import this data and run program in R then export the result of R script into ourside of image in .img or ENVI format. Both are ok. I don't know much about R. Just someone give me the script run on the imported image in R. But I don't know how to import and export multiband image to and from R.

Comment: you may find [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html) useful.

Comment: So why do you need to use `R` in the first place?  If someone gave you `R` scripts to process ENVI images, then make that person give you the I/O code as well.  FWIW, the ENVI format is well-defined on the web and further a SO search for "[r] ENVI" yields a lot of existing questions.

Comment: BTW,  if you do need to use `R`,  `caTools::readENVI` is a useful tool here.

Comment: That scripts is not dedicated for my case, just example script.

Comment: It seems ENVI format is not broadly used in R. So what format should I convert the ENVI files to be read easily in R?

Comment: Use brick in raster (via rgdal) to read it. GeoTIFF is a great alternative format if you must resort to that.